# Disable toolbar collapsing on scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, toolbar

I have an activity with a toolbar, which hides when i scroll the scrollview, however, the content is not that much bigger than a phone screen, so i want to disable the hiding of the toolbar, since it makes no sense. How do i do this?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/svCreateAdvert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".CreateAdvert">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/create_advert_container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/createAdvertToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Place the toolbar outside of your scrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing the toolbar outside of your scrollview, scrolling will not effect the toolbar.

You will need to add an extra linearlayout around the toolbar & scrollview like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/create_advert_container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/createAdvertToolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svCreateAdvert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".CreateAdvert">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```